# SQL Server JOIN missing NULL values from left table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have two tables in SQL Server:

```
  Table1:                               Table2:

  Col1(PK):      Col2:                  Col1:              
  ------------------------              ------
  1              1                      1                     
  2              <null>                 2                 
  3              5                      10                     
  4              <null>                 11                 
  5              12                     12
```

Now I want join these tables on `Col2` but in result I want have all rows with `Col2` where value is null and if not null only rows that `Col2` exist in `Table2`.

When I try use `Left Join` in result have row from `Col1(PK) = 3` but `Col2 = 5` does not exist in `Table2`.

How can I achieve it?

I tried something like this, but it only returns the matched lines and ignores the null ones

```sql
select * 
from Table1 t1 
join Table2 t2 on t1.Col2 = t2.Col1 or t1.Col2 is null and t2.Col1 is null
```

Expected rows in result Col1(PK) 1,2,4,5.
Because null in T1.Col2 is ok, and in T1.Col2 value in row 1(1) and 5(12) exist in T2.Col1

Something like
If T1.Col2 == null => Is Ok Can Return
If T1.Col2 != null => Check If Exists Value in T2.Col1 => Exists Is ok Can Return, Not Exists Skip

Comment: Show what you've tried so far...

Comment: Please provide the desired output for your example. It'll be easier to understand

Comment: "value is null and if not null" That doesn't make sense. You might mean "value is null or if not null" & you might mean "and the rows where if not null"--both are the same. Write a clear statement about the rows you want that makes sense. Use enough words, sentences & references to parts of examples to clearly & fully say what you mean. When giving a business relation(ship)/association or table (base or query result), say what a row in it states about the business situation in terms of its column values.

Comment: I want to return all rows from Table1 where Col2 is null or Value in Col2 exist in Table2.Col1

Answer (score 0):

I would use `NOT NULL` and `EXISTS` as mentioned in your description

```
select *
from table1 t1
where col2 is null or exists (
  select 1
  from table2 t2
  where t1.col2 = t2.col1
)
```

Comment: I am looking for a solution that does not use a where clause

Comment: @blane Why? Do you shop for cars without wheels or seats?

Comment: Because in Where clause I have conditions under which the user wants to filter something from DB (web grid). In table2 I have a list of IDs to which the user has access (permissions), but if in Table1.Col2 is null, I don't want such entries to be cut out.

Answer (score 0):

Inner joins will return only the matching records and null values are simply ignored in a join condition. Null cannot be compared with a null, because there is no value.

Assuming that you have col2 in table2, you can try using left join.

```
select * 
from Table1 t1 
full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 
where t2.col2 is not null or t1.col2 is null;
```

Comment: But when I use LEFT JOIN in result will have rows from T1 with T1.Col2 Value that not exist in T2.Col1

Comment: I'm sorry, I might have misunderstood the scenario. Now I understand. we can go with full outer join 

select * 
from Table1 t1 
full outer join Table2 t2 on t1.Col2 = t2.Col2 where t2.col2 is not null or t1.col2 is null;

Comment: Almost perfect, however, it returns blank rows for all rows in table2 that failed to match the rows in table1. So if in Table2 we have 5 rows, but in Table1 there are only 3 matching results, the result will be 5 rows, of which for two rows, the columns of Table1 will be empty (null)